# My website is down for some countries/cities

Tags: domain-name-system

Recently I've created a website and set up a domain name in .xyz zone. The sever is being hosted in Russia, domain name provided by whois.com. Approximately 3-4 days have passed since that and, according to https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime tests, my website is offline for at least 50% of the cities it checks. I live in Russia and it is online for me (tested with 2 different ISPs), but even some Russian services can't access it (dns lookup fail, I guess).

Is this DNS propagation thing taking so long?

updated: domain name http://metathought.xyz . ps. not a spam, it's just an empty blog with nothing on it.

Comment: Could you please provide the domain name in question so we can do more checks on it, because on Serverfault there are similar posts about the new gLTDS not updating even after almost two weeks etc. I will update my answer. EDIT
1) Do you host your own NS ?
2) Is the webserver on the same machine as the ns ? From there on, we can do something, if needed can reply in russian also :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have two sets of nameservers - four from `whois.com` and two from `spaceweb.ru`. I suspect this is not intended, as the `whois.com` nameservers don't return any IPs for the domain, but `spaceweb.ru` does.

[image]

Comment: Should I delete all entries with ns*.whois.com ?

Comment: @ibe If spaceweb.ru is your intended DNS provider, then yes.